# Looking for a dynamic, thumbnail grid gallery that expands one image on hover and shrinks the others

Tags: jquery, dynamic, hover, gallery, expand

I hope you understand what I'm looking for. I've been searching for days but can't find anything. Is there something available like this for jquery for example? It should look like this:

jsfiddle.net/sGDvj/1/

but instead of the image just zooming out, the objects around it should move around in the grid.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for something similar. I found this, not sure it fits your needs? http://gridster.net/demos/expandable-widgets.html

Also check out this one:

http://www.jsonenglish.com/projects/flex/